# Python MySQL Foreign Key Error

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to build a MySQL database which will hold shortest route information I get back from a Google API.

The code for creating tables is shown below. As can be seen, the request_no is generated by MySQL using auto-increment. This request_no is the primary key for the master table which holds the overall results from the API request. The leg table, holds the constitutive parts of the API request. The request_no must relate to its respective leg_no parts, as seen in the second part, the leg_data table.

```
TABLES={}
TABLES['master'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `master` ("
    "  `request_no` int AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,"
    "  `distance` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `duration` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `duration_in_traffic` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `Orig_lat` double NOT NULL,"
    "  `Orig_lng` double NOT NULL,"
    "  `Orig_address` longtext ,"
    "  `Dest_lat` double NOT NULL,"
    "  `Dest_lng` double NOT NULL,"
    "  `Dest_address` longtext ,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`request_no`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

TABLES['leg_data'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `leg_data` ("
    "  `leg_no` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `request_no` int NOT NULL,"
    "  `leg_distance` int ,"
    "  `leg_duration` int ,"
    "  `leg_travel_mode` longtext ,"
    "  `leg_Orig_lat` double ,"
    "  `leg_Orig_lng` double ,"
    "  `leg_Dest_lat` double ,"
    "  `leg_Dest_lng` double ,"
    "  `leg_html_inst` longtext ,"
    "  `leg_polyline` longtext ,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`leg_no`),"
    "  CONSTRAINT `leg_data_ibfk` FOREIGN KEY (`request_no`)"
    "     REFERENCES `master` (`request_no`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
```

I then insert values which are parsed from the API JSON response.

EDITED, now using `request_no: cursor.lastrowid`

```
add_overall_data = ("INSERT INTO master" 
    "(date_time, distance, duration, duration_in_traffic, Orig_lat, Orig_lng, Orig_address, Dest_lat, Dest_lng, Dest_address)"
    "VALUES (%(date_time)s, %(distance)s, %(duration)s, %(duration_in_traffic)s, %(Orig_lat)s, %(Orig_lng)s, %(Orig_address)s, %(Dest_lat)s, %(Dest_lng)s, %(Dest_address)s)")

add_leg_data = ("INSERT INTO leg_data"
    "(request_no, leg_distance, leg_duration, leg_Orig_lat, leg_Orig_lng, leg_Dest_lat, leg_Dest_lng, leg_html_inst, leg_polyline, leg_travel_mode)" 
    "VALUES (%(request_no)s, %(leg_distance)s, %(leg_duration)s, %(leg_Orig_lat)s, %(leg_Orig_lng)s, %(leg_Dest_lat)s, %(leg_Dest_lng)s, %(leg_html_inst)s, %(leg_polyline)s, %(leg_travel_mode)s)")

for result in results:
    if result["status"] == "OK":
        for leg in result['routes'][0]['legs']:
            params = {
            "date_time": leg['_date_time'],
            "distance": leg['distance']['value'],
            "duration": leg['duration']['value'],
            "duration_in_traffic": leg['duration_in_traffic']['value'],
            "Orig_lat": leg['start_location']['lat'],
            "Orig_lng": leg['start_location']['lng'],
            "Orig_address": leg['start_address'],
            "Dest_lat": leg['end_location']['lat'],
            "Dest_lng": leg['end_location']['lng'],
            "Dest_address": leg['end_address']
            }
            cursor.execute(add_overall_data, params)
        for steps in result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']:
            params = {
            "request_no": cursor.lastrowid,
            "leg_distance": steps['distance']['value'],
            "leg_duration": steps['duration']['value'],
            "leg_Orig_lat": steps['start_location']['lat'],
            "leg_Orig_lng": steps['start_location']['lng'],
            "leg_Dest_lat": steps['end_location']['lat'],
            "leg_Dest_lng": steps['end_location']['lng'],
            "leg_html_inst": steps['html_instructions'],
            "leg_polyline": steps['polyline']['points'],
            "leg_travel_mode": steps['travel_mode']
            } 
            cursor.execute(add_leg_data, params)
```

I am now able to populate the request_no field in the leg_data table. Albeit with incorrect values. What cursor. argument could I use to associate the individual legs with their respective master id (request_no)?

Answer (score 2):

When writing to the `leg_data` table, you need to provide a `request_no` which corresponds to a value under the `request_no` column in the `master` table.

UPDATE:
Unfortunately 'date_time' is not unique, as there can be up to 10 records received from the API per second.
The syntax below does indeed work. The combination of Orig_lat,Orig_lng,Dest_lat and Dest_lng will be unique, despite its clunkiness. How could I change the 'WHERE' statement below to reference all 4 parameters above?

```
for result in results:
    if result["status"] == "OK":
        for leg in result['routes'][0]['legs']:
            params = {
            "date_time": leg['_date_time'],
            "distance": leg['distance']['value'],
            "duration": leg['duration']['value'],
            "duration_in_traffic": leg['duration_in_traffic']['value'],
            "Orig_lat": leg['start_location']['lat'],
            "Orig_lng": leg['start_location']['lng'],
            "Orig_address": leg['start_address'],
            "Dest_lat": leg['end_location']['lat'],
            "Dest_lng": leg['end_location']['lng'],
            "Dest_address": leg['end_address']
            }
            cursor.execute(add_overall_data, params)
            cursor.execute(
                'SELECT request_no FROM master WHERE date_time = {}'.format(
                    leg['_date_time']
                )
            )
            request_no = cursor.fetchOne()[0]
        for steps in result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']:
            params = {
            "request_no": request_no,
            "leg_distance": steps['distance']['value'],
            "leg_duration": steps['duration']['value'],
            "leg_Orig_lat": steps['start_location']['lat'],
            "leg_Orig_lng": steps['start_location']['lng'],
            "leg_Dest_lat": steps['end_location']['lat'],
            "leg_Dest_lng": steps['end_location']['lng'],
            "leg_html_inst": steps['html_instructions'],
            "leg_polyline": steps['polyline']['points'],
            "leg_travel_mode": steps['travel_mode']
            } 
            cursor.execute(add_leg_data, params)
```

UPDATE 2: If `date_time` isn't sufficient to uniquely identify a record, then you can add as many columns as you'd like to the query:

```
cursor.execute(
    'SELECT request_no FROM master WHERE col1 = {} AND col2 = {} AND ...'.format(
        val1, val2, ...
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks mattm. Agreed, how do I go about that? Do I query the DB and then associate? I am confused, as the documentation shows an example, which I have closely followed, which is able to associate these - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-ddl.html

Comment: The link you posted shows nothing about inserting records.

Comment: Apologies - next page - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Comment: Yes, in that example they are passing in the `emp_no`.

Comment: After this line: `cursor.execute(add_overall_data, params)`, you need to determine what the `record_no` is of the row you just created, and then use that value as the `record_no` for all of your `INSERT` statements into `leg_data`.

Comment: Thanks mattm. Could you suggest methods for doing this?

Comment: Thank you @mattm. Now I am getting 'code'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064'code' I believe this isn't working as I have around 10 records per second and so date_time does not provide the granularity needed. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks @mattm. I believe a change is also needed to the cursor.fetchone()[] section. I have tried fetchmany and fetchall, both are leading to "Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type" errors

Comment: `fetchall()` is going to give you back a list of tuples, so it'd be something like `cursor.fetchall()[0][0]`. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods

Comment: Thanks @mattm. Same error with that unfortunately. I shall dig a little deeper. Thank you